# I want to change image on button clicked in unity through event system through different script

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have two scripts Product and ProductUI i want to call event to ProuductUI through Product script
basically i am making a game where you have two button's "Yes button" & "No Button" i want to change UI image to next image irrespective of whether it click on  "Yes button" or "No Button"
my code is working but it but sometimes you have to click on button more than once to change image

my Code

Product Manager script Code

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.EventSystems;
using System;

public class ProductManager : MonoBehaviour
{
    private ProductUI productUI;
    public event EventHandler onInputDone;
  
    private void Awake()
    {
        productUI = FindObjectOfType<ProductUI>();
    }


    public void Yes_NO()
    {
        onInputDone?.Invoke(this, EventArgs.Empty);
        if (EventSystem.current.currentSelectedGameObject.name == "yesButton")
        {
           
        }
        else if(EventSystem.current.currentSelectedGameObject.name == "noButton")
        {
          
        }

   
    }

   
}
```

Product UI Script Code

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using System;

public class ProductUI : MonoBehaviour
{
    private ProductList productList;
    private Image image;
    private int random;
    [SerializeField] private ProductManager productManager;

    private void Start()
    {
        image = GetComponent<Image>();
        productList = Resources.Load<ProductList>(typeof(ProductList).Name); //acess product list
        productManager = FindObjectOfType<ProductManager>();
        random = UnityEngine.Random.Range(0, productList.list.Count);
        image.sprite = productList.list[random].productSprite;

        productManager.onInputDone += onInputDone;
    }

    private void onInputDone(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int newRandom = UnityEngine.Random.Range(0, productList.list.Count);
        image.sprite = productList.list[newRandom].productSprite;
        random = newRandom;
    }
```

Comment: in `onInputDone` you assign a random image from a list of images. Random means you could actually assign the same image to a object twice in a row. Is that intended?

Comment: No , its not indented...

Comment: Happens lol. So I guess that's the problem you were trying to solve?

Comment: yeah it repeatedly giving me same image

Comment: I'm glad it's resolved then!

Comment: Well random means it could be the same image multiple times in a row. If you want it to be any image *except* the one you are currently using you have to keep track of the image currently in use and exclude that from the random function. You could create a new list where you delete the one currently in use or just do another random "roll" until you get a new one.

Comment: yeah i was thinking kind of same

Comment: Please use the correct tags! Note that [`unityscript`](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/unityscript/info) is or better **was** a JavaScript flavor like custom language used in early Unity versions and is long **deprecated** by now!